# map api code nearbysearch

Tags: php, json, google-maps, dictionary

i'm got error what is this problem? how i get echo getAddress ?i'm tried eny time to fix that?

```
function getAddress($la, $lo){
  $ur= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=".$la.",".$lo."&radius=10&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c"
   $json = file_get_contents($ur);

   $data = json_decode($json);
   $status = $data->status;
   $name= '';
     if($status == "OK"){
      $addr = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
     }
   return $addr;
  } 
          echo getAddress("6.154841","80.700845");
```

Comment: Do you even get any output? Try to print your `$addr` before you return it in your function and look for the result.

Comment: what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: i'm got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE i

Comment: $json = file_get_contents($ur);what is this problem? i can't get output

Comment: Put the semocolon(;) at the end of $ur variable like

$ur= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=".$la.",".$lo."&radius=10&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a semi colon **;** at the end of `$ur`

`$ur= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?
location=".$la.",".$lo."&radius=10&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c";`